# How to pass argument to script which is input to bash

Tags: bash, pipe, curl, input

Right now I have one-liner like this:

```
curl -fsSL http://git.io/vvZMn | bash
```

It is downloading script and passing it to bash as stdin file. I would like to run this script with additional argument `print`.

Maybe something like this?

```
curl -fsSL http://git.io/vvZMn | bash -- print
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What are you expecting `print` to do here?  Display the commands being run?  If so, try `bash -x`.    Note: this `curl | bash` routine is a massive security hole; you don't get the see what will be run until your server has been pwned.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `-s` option.  With `-s`, you can pass arguments to the script.

As a dummy example to illustrate this:

```
$ echo 'echo 1=$1' | bash -s -- Print
1=Print
```

Here, you can see that the script provided on stdin is given the positional parameter `Print`.  Your script takes a `-u UUID` argument and that can be accommodated also:

```
$ echo 'echo arguments=$*' | bash -s -- -u UUID print
arguments=-u UUID print
```

So, in your case:

```
curl -fsSL http://git.io/vvZMn | bash -s -- print
```

Or,

```
curl -fsSL http://git.io/vvZMn | bash -s -- -u UUID print
```

As Stephen Harris pointed out, downloading a script and executing it, sight unseen, is a security concern.

Answer (score 3):

If your system has `/dev/stdin`, you can use

```
$ echo 'echo 1=$1' | bash /dev/stdin print
1=print
```

Do ***not*** do this:

```
$ echo 'echo 1=$1' | bash /dev/stdin -- print
1=--
```

If you want to use `--`, do this:

```
$ echo 'echo 1=$1' | bash -- /dev/stdin print
1=print
```